# Change textbox value inside event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have scanner event when this event occur I have code to save what I read it by scanner to textbox .

When I am tracing this it is work fine but nothing showing on the screen for user

This code inside button click:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Instantiate CoreScanner Class
            cCoreScannerClass = new CCoreScannerClass();
            //Call Open API
            short[] scannerTypes = new short[1];//Scanner Types you are interested in
            scannerTypes[0] = 1; // 1 for all scanner types
            short numberOfScannerTypes = 1; // Size of the scannerTypes array
            int status; // Extended API return code
            cCoreScannerClass.Open(0, scannerTypes, numberOfScannerTypes, out status);
            // Subscribe for barcode events in cCoreScannerClass
            cCoreScannerClass.BarcodeEvent += new
            _ICoreScannerEvents_BarcodeEventEventHandler(OnBarcodeEvent);
            // Let's subscribe for events
            int opcode = 1001; // Method for Subscribe events
            string outXML; // XML Output
            string inXML = "<inArgs>" +
            "<cmdArgs>" +
            "<arg-int>1</arg-int>" + // Number of events you want to subscribe
            "<arg-int>1</arg-int>" + // Comma separated event IDs
            "</cmdArgs>" +
            "</inArgs>";
            cCoreScannerClass.ExecCommand(opcode, ref inXML, out outXML, out status);
            Console.WriteLine(outXML);

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something wrong please check... " + exp.Message);
        }
    }
```

This code after event occur :

```
void OnBarcodeEvent(short eventType, ref string pscanData)
{
    first = pscanData;
      printfunction();

        }
```

this code after printfunction function to write to textbox  :

```
private void printfunction()
    {
        int l = first.IndexOf("<datalabel>");
        second = first.Substring(l + 11);
        int j = second.IndexOf("</datalabel>");
        second = second.Substring(0,j-1);

        string newValue = second.Replace("0x", ""); ;
        newValue = newValue.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        txt = GetStringFromAsciiHex(newValue);
       TextBox1.Text = txt;
     }
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does your local variable `txt` contain the correct value? If so, try `TextBox1.Refresh()` after setting the text.

Comment: you could have asked this as a comment.

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi: I posted it as an answer because it does not only contain a question, but provides also a potential answer.

Comment: i get this error TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Refresh' and no extension method 'Refresh' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'